# Reset flags back to normal using gpio-cdev and Rust in Raspberry Pi

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, gpio

So, I got access to a line offset from cdev using the `gpio-cdev` library in Rust. I requested certain flags on it, and at the end, I want to set it back to normal. Here's the code that I wrote

```rust
use gpio_cdev::{Chip, LineRequestFlags};

let chip = Chip::new("/dev/gpiochip0");
let line = chip.get_line(10).unwrap();
line
    .request(
       LineRequestFlags::OUTPUT,
       0,
       &format!("rpi-gpio-{}", self.line.offset()),
    )
    .unwrap();
```

Now, I want to set it back to normal

```
line
   .request(
       LineRequestFlags::empty(),
       0,
       "",
   )
   .unwrap();
```

Comment: So, do you experience any issue with that? If you read the documentation, the closing line will return it to *normal*, whatever that means. Actually the behaviour is driver specific and not specified on that level. But user space should not make any assumptions on that.

Answer (score 0):

That was actually tricky. I had to use `libc::close()` on the raw file descriptor of the handle, which required using unsafe block

```rust
libc::close(unsafe { line_handle.as_raw_fd() })
```